# How to replace even character of words in a string with "dash" or "symbol"?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, string-function

I am trying to extract words from a string, then replace the even characters with dash..(not include white space) to make a kind of hints for a word game. For example:

> InputString="English Language"
>
> OutputString = "#n#l#s# #a#g#a#e"

Currently, I use this code below:

```
Private Sub Hint()

    Dim InputString as string = "English Language"
    dim SubInput as string()
    SubInput=InputString.Split(" ")

    For i=0 to UBound(SubInput) 'run through all items in SubInput array

        For k=0 to SubInput(i).length-1 'run through all characters in one item 

        If k mod 2= 0 then 'Do the replacement if even characters found
                SubInput(i)=SubInput(i).Replace(SubInput(i).Chars(k),"#") 
        End If

        Next

    Next

    Dim OutputString=String.Join(" ",subInput(i))
    Msgbox(OutputString)

    End Sub
```

However, I got the message box showing this "

> **#n#l#s# #a###a#e**

"
The word: **Language** is wrongly replaced at character no (3)

Could you point out how to get it fixed?

Thank you very much ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this code.much simple to implement and understand

```
Dim s As String = "English Language"
        Dim intcount As Integer = 0
        For Each c As Char In s
            If intcount Mod 2 = 0 and c <> "" Then
                s = s.Remove(intcount, 1).Insert(intcount, "#")
            End If
            intcount += 1
        Next
 Return s
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Akhil Kumar ~ I find out one thing that, if the input string has more than 2 words, the code replaces also the white space. So, I modified the condition like this:`If intcount Mod 2=0 and c <> " " then`. Now it works perfectly with any number of words in the string. Could you modify the above code so that other people could benefit from it. Thank you ~

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=^(?:\S\S|\s\S|\S\s)*).
```

You can use this and replace by `#`.[See Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E(%3F%3A%5CS%5CS%7C%5Cs%5CS%7C%5CS%5Cs)*).&i=English%20Language&r=%23)

Comment: Thanks @VKS. I will learn on using Regex. At the moment, I can not understand that expression ^^".

Comment: @GarenaPlusBeta its a lokkbehind stating the only even should be behind the character we are replacing.

Answer (score 1):

As per [vks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759324/3682599)  regex will be much better.You can achieve the output in a single line of code.

```
 Dim InputString As String = "English Language"
 OutputString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(InputString, "(?<=^(?:\S\S|\s\S|\S\s)*).", "#")
```

`(?<=^(?:\S\S|\s\S|\S\s)*).` -  is the pattern to filter(*finds the characters in even index of input string*) your input string to replace with `#`

[`Live Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO)

---

Learn regex for vb.net from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx),[tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: That is a great outpoint from  you wingedpanther. I don't know that regex is that versatile. Definitely heading to learn it. Thank you @wingedpanther ~

Comment: I think you are at advanced level. VKS. you don't need credit :D

Comment: @GarenaPlusBeta NVM, let him grow :D

Comment: @vks _i didnt see the tag and answered thinking its a C# question_ , no I don't believe this because OP is mentioned the code(`vb.net`) used in the question so it's very clear that code isn't C# :D. At least `Dim InputString as string` will tell you what is the code

Comment: @wingedpanther i actually didnt see d tag!!!!!! newaz does work in vb.net as well....verified :) i got no idea about `dim` etc....m just aware of d regex part

Comment: wow, that it great @wingedpanther. Stackoverflow is also very interactive, just like facebook.^^. Yup, definitely taking some regex lessons from your links now. Thank you very much ~

Comment: I tried to add more words to the string and it replace also the white space. Could you modify the code to work with any number of words in InputString? @wingedpanther and vks ~.

Comment: @GarenaPlusBeta Give a sample input or make use of  https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO

Comment: Yes, I tried the fiddle and for example the Input String is: English Language Learning it would result #n#l#s# #a#g#a#e#L#a#n#n# . I mean if you could modify the code above then people may benefit from it . At the moment, I have no knowledge of regex to modify the code ^^'. I use the code posted above by Kumar with a little change to make it work with any number of words in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Try out linq  as below,

```
   string s = "English Language";
   string[] split = s.Split(" ");
   for(int j=0;j<split.length;j++)
   {
    var outStr = string.Concat(split[j].Select((c,i) => i%2==0 ? "#" : c.ToString()));
    split[j]= outStr;
   }
   s= String.Join(" ",split);
```

Code is in C# but you can use converter to convert it in vb.net

Comment: Thank you for your help, Pranay. I try it but it shows an error with variable  "i" is hidden....something. The below code of Kumar works well for it. Thanks

Comment: Let me try it @Pranay Rana